Woocommerce price filter widget always shows max price of most expensive product in the whole shop
In my Woocommerce shop I use the price filter widget. In my opinion it should only show the max price of the current products in a category or search result, but it always shows the max price of the most expensive item in the shop. Is there a way to fix it?
